# error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to get parameter from cmd and pass that parameter to method Fibonacci, but I am getting some error. Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error?

Thank you.

**Code:**

```
class fibo {

static void Fibonacci(int Total,int n1,int n2){

    if(Total > 1){      
        int sum = n1 + n2;
        System.out.print(sum + " ");
        n1 = n2;
        n2 = sum;
        --Total;
        Fibonacci(Total,n1,n2);
    }
}

}

class main{

    public static void main(String args[]){

    fibo f = new fibo();    
    System.out.print(0 + " ");
    System.out.print(1 + " ");
    int Total = args[0];
    int n1 = args[1];
    int n2 = args[2];    
    f.Fibonacci(Total,n1,n2);


    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
fibonacci.java:26: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int
int Total = args[0];

fibonacci.java:27: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int

    int n1 = args[1];

fibonacci.java:28: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int

int n2 = args[2];

3 errors
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int n1 = args[1];
int n2 = args[2];
```

You are trying to assign `String` to `int` directly. No, that won't work.

`args` is `String` array and it contains Strings. So when you try to assign a value from it to an integer varaible you should convert.

For ex :

```
int n1 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
```

Same with other assignments as well.

Comment: thanks that is what i wanted